# Sort list in a dict that has key as a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort a list by keys of dict that has keys as a lists with other dicts.

```
big_list = [{"Key1": 1, "Key2" :2, "Key3": [{"sortable_key": value1, value2, ..}]}]
```

The goal is to sort the big_list by sortable_key. I am trying to accomplish sorting by using lambda:

```
big_list = list(sorted(big_list, key=lambda x: x["Key3"]["sortable_key"]))
```

But this is not working (not sorting the list, I assume that it would sort it in particular order like alphabetical). Am I trying to access the sortable_key in a wrong manner or is this not achievable by using lambda?

Thanks!

Full example of big_list:

```
big_list = [{'number': '7',
  'code': '1106',
  'name': 'John',
  'det': [{'subcode': 'AA11','subname': 'Alan','age': 11},
{'subcode': 'CC11','subname': 'Hugo','age': 22},
{'subcode': 'BB11','subname': 'Walt','age': 18}]}]
```

In this case I need to sort list by 'subcode'.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? what does it do? What should you sort on if there are more than one value in `key3`?

Comment: Value of `Key3` is a list, maybe `x["Key3"][0]["sortable_key"]`. Also could you provide full example of `big_list`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `[0]` since `x["Key3"]`is a list:

```
big_list = list(sorted(big_list, key=lambda x: x["Key3"][0]["sortable_key"]))
```

Comment: This assumes all `key3`'s have at least one element and the first value is the only one that matters.